# How to integrate redux-form's onSubmit with redux-api-middleware?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I'm writing a React / Redux app using [redux-form](http://redux-form.com/) and [redux-api-middleware](https://github.com/agraboso/redux-api-middleware), and I'm having trouble integrating redux-form's `onSubmit` function with the RSAA lifecycle.

The redux-form documentation says that the `onSubmit` handler [should](http://redux-form.com/5.3.1/#/api/reduxForm?_k=pvbdls) [return](http://redux-form.com/5.3.1/#/examples/submit-validation?_k=o8zxe2) a Promise. Until `resolve` is called on the promise, the form's `submitting` prop will be `true`.

However, in this app my API calls don't currently use promises (e.g. via `fetch`). I make API calls by dispatching a `[CALL_API]` RSAA action and [reducing redux-api-middleware's response actions.](https://github.com/agraboso/redux-api-middleware#success-type-descriptors)

### Problem code

```js
class MyReduxFormContainer extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MyReduxForm submit={this.props.submit} />
    )
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    submit: function(values, dispatch) {
      dispatch({
        [CALL_API]: {
          method: 'PATCH',
          types: [
            {
              type: 'REQUEST',
              endpoint: '...',
              body: JSON.stringify(values)
            },
            'SUCCESS',
            'FAILURE'
          ]
        }
      });
      // Problem: redux-api-middleware-style API calls normally don't leverage promises.
      // Out of the box, this library doesn't offer a promise to return.
    }
  }
};

export default connect(
  // ...
  mapDispatchToProps
)(MyReduxFormContainer)
```

### Possible Solutions

**I could pass a promise through the `payload` RSAA callback,** which could then resolve/reject the promise after the API response, but this seems to violate the rule that *"action creators should't cause side-effects."* Granting that redux-api-middleware seems to bend this rule.

**I could in theory just use `fetch` inside the `onSubmit` handler**, instead of redux-api-middleware, but this isn't just a concession which makes my API interactions inconsistent across the application, it also risks duplicating any API middleware activities I've baked in, e.g. setting default headers, de-camelizing / camelizing payloads, etc.

Does anyone have experience using redux-form and redux-api-middleware together?

**If it were just redux-api-middleware,** I would have expected to simply change the form's `submitting` prop by altering the form's state when reducing the `ACTION_TYPE_[REQUEST|SUCCESS|FAILURE]` action types. But it seems non-standard and potentially risky to directly modify the *form's* state from a reducer. Example redux-form implementations seem to emphasize that redux-form state should be transparent / only indirectly manipulated.

Any thoughts / pointers would be greatly appreciated!

### Related GitHub issues

redux-api-middleware:

- https://github.com/agraboso/redux-api-middleware/issues/21
- https://github.com/agraboso/redux-api-middleware/issues/53

redux-form:

- https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/777

Answer (score 3):

Recently I found quite elegant and generic way combine it. [Here is article with explanation](http://randycoulman.com/blog/2016/05/03/redux-and-forms-and-apis-oh-my/)

```
export const formToApiAdapter = (dispatch, actionCreator, formatErrors) => (
  (...args) => (
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => (
      dispatch(actionCreator(...args)).then(
        (response) => {
          if (response.error) {
            return reject(formatErrors(response));
          }
          return resolve(response);
        }
      )
    ))
  )
);
```

Comment: This solution refreshes form component on submit :|

Answer (score 2):

For lack of a better solution, I'm currently wrapping my `dispatch({[CALL_API]})` call inside of a Promise, within the redux-form `submit` handler.

```js
class MyReduxFormContainer extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MyReduxForm submit={this.props.submit} />
    )
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    submit: function(values, dispatch) {

      // Solution: Wrap the [CALL_API] dispatch in a Promise
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        dispatch({
          [CALL_API]: {
            method: 'PATCH',
            types: [
              {
                type: 'MY_PATCH_REQUEST'
                endpoint: '...',
                body: JSON.stringify(values)
              },
              {
                type: 'MY_PATCH_SUCCESS',
                payload: function (action, state, res) {

                  // Solution: resolve() the promise in the SUCCESS payload callback
                  // Changes `submitting` prop of MyReduxForm
                  resolve();

                }
              },
              {
                type: 'MY_PATCH_FAILURE',
                payload: function (action, state, res) {

                  // Solution: reject() the promise in the FAILURE payload callback
                  // Changes `submitting` prop of MyReduxForm
                  reject();

                }
              }
            ]
          }
        });

      });

    }
  }
};

export default connect(
  // ...
  mapDispatchToProps
)(MyReduxFormContainer)
```

Ultimately I'm pretty unhappy with this code architecture, and at this point I think standard `fetch` usage would have been preferable to `redux-api-middleware`.

Triggering effects after API responses is standard enough as a concern, there ought to be more elegant solutions than this kind of callback nesting, e.g. using a promise chain.

Comment: Did you ever found a better solution?